# setting multiline text on Android EditText widget

Tags: android, text

I read a multiline text from a .txt file, then I setText, but all linefeeds are gone, what am I missing? ( editor has android:inputType="textMultiLine" set):

```
BufferedReader r;
r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(AbrarFilePaths.NotebooksPath() + fileName));
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line = r.readLine()) != null) 
  { total.append(line);}
editor.setText(total);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
while((line = r.readLine()) != null) 
  { total.append(line + "\n");}
editor.setText(total);
```

And set MaxLines to 1000 for example.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Set this property in your xml file android:maxLines=" 10" 10 lines in edittext.

or you can try

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/msgText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:padding="5dip">
</EditText>
```

Comment: nope, not working. The problem is with setText, it eats carriage returns!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think EditText can detect New Line character. You might have to build a custom component to handle that

Comment: so why we can type new lines in it? I don't agree